# Problem with dimension lines (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew this picture with TikZ. How can I complete that dimension line?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt] {standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm]
\draw [color=black,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (2.0,0.0) circle (0.5cm);
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (0.0,6.0)-- (-2.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (0.0,6.0)-- (2.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=1.0pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (2.0,0.0)-- (-2.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=1.0pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (0.0,6.0)-- (-0.003238033414928232,0.0);
%quote
\draw (-0.9300042508665818,6.310001416955528)-- (-2.930004250866582,0.3100014169555273);
%\draw (-2.0,-1.094507989900869)-- (2.0,-1.094507989900869);
\draw (-2.0,-1.094507989900869)-- (2.0,-1.094507989900869);
\draw (-2.0,-0.85)-- (-2.0,-1.35);
\draw (2.0,-0.85)-- (2.0,-1.35);
\begin{scriptsize}

\draw[color=black] (-2.0,3.229250320291161) node {\Large $x$ cm};
%\draw[color=black] (0.7988152988075463,3.0491975314248916) node {$f$};
\draw[color=black] (0.0,-0.7) node {\Large $y$ cm};
%\draw[color=black] (-0.21602769298415597,3.1474081435337657) node {$h$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* you mean the *x* dimension line -- your use of the word "quote" doesn't get this message across.

Comment: If you do mean that, how about drawing the whole dimension including the text then rotating it?

Comment: I don't know how can I draw a parallel segment quickly in latex and i don't know how to rotate the 2 segment. :S

Comment: Alternative: you're importing `tikzlibrary{arrows}` already -- check out and specify the `|` arrow head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need it for this one figure (and not for more), then you can set a quick style like the following (it requires `arrows.meta`):

```
\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=5mm]}-{|[width=5mm]}}
}
```

Then simply write the commands like this (the node is included in the path):

```
\draw[quote] (-0.9300042508665818,6.310001416955528) -- 
    (-2.930004250866582,0.3100014169555273) node[left, midway] {\Large $x$ cm};
\draw[quote] (-2.0,-1.094507989900869) -- 
    (2.0,-1.094507989900869) node[above, midway] {\Large $x$ cm};
```

And you get this (ignore the faulty color):

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}

\tikzset{
    quote/.style={{|[width=5mm]}-{|[width=5mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    line cap=round,line join=round,
    >=triangle 45,
    x=0.8cm,y=0.8cm,
    every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]

\draw [fill=yellow, opacity=.5] (2.0,0.0) circle (0.5cm);
% Triangle
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (-2.0,0.0) -- (0.0,6.0) -- (2.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=1pt,densely dashed] (2.0,0.0)-- (-2.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=1pt,densely dashed] (0.0,6.0)-- (-0.003238033414928232,0.0);

\draw[quote] (-0.9300042508665818,6.310001416955528) -- 
    (-2.930004250866582,0.3100014169555273) node[left, midway] {$x$ cm};
\draw[quote] (-2.0,-1.094507989900869)-- (2.0,-1.094507989900869) node[above, midway] {$x$ cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

1. You don't need to specify `\draw[color=black]` or even `\draw[black]`, since that's the default color.
2. If you want the nodes (all of them) to have small text than add this next to your `tikzpicture`:

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\scriptsize}]
   ...
   ```
3. Be careful because you setting them to be small, yet you wrote `... {\Large $x$ cm};`

Comment: can you post your entire code?

Comment: @ryuk See edit. :)

Answer (score 2):

With use of `arrow.meta` and some simplification and modification of measures appearance:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz] {standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274,0.25098039215686274}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    line cap=round, line join=round,
    quote/.style = {{Bar[width=3mm]}-{Bar[width=3mm]}},
    >={Straight Barb[]}, 
    x=0.8cm, y=0.8cm]
\draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (2.0,0.0) circle (0.5cm);
\draw[line width=1.5pt] (0.0,6.0)-- (-2.0,0.0) 
                        (0.0,6.0)-- (2.0,0.0);
\draw[line width=1.0pt,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] 
                        (2.0,0.0)-- (-2.0,0.0)
                        (0.0,6.0)-- (-0.003238033414928232,0.0);
% measures
\draw[quote] (-0.9300042508665818,6.310001416955528)--
node[above,sloped] {$x$ cm}   (-2.930004250866582,0.3100014169555273);
\draw[quote] (-2.0,-1.094507989900869) --
node[above] {$x$ cm} (2.0,-1.094507989900869);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Or alternative with combined line heads:

[image]

where the `quotes` is defined as:

```
quote/.style = {{Bar[width=3mm]Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[]Bar[width=3mm]}},
```

Comment: thank you! unfortunately there is this error! :(

I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex' \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

Comment: @ryuk You should update your packages. :)

Comment: i don't know how can I update the package with tikz! :(

Comment: @ryuk How did you install your Tex distribution?

Comment: @ryuk, You can upgrade your instalation with tools accompanied your LaTeX instalation. For example, if you have MikTeX (as I do), select "Update" and in open window select package repository (nearest or select one of listed in option"Let me choose a remote package repository") and that is. Recent MikTeX upgrade is major one, so it goin in two pass.

Comment: I have texwork. Is the same procedure to upgrade?

Comment: @ryuk Yes, I think. Open Tex Live Utility, that is what you use to upgrade.

Comment: TeXwork is an editor. It come width MikTeX as well width TeXLive. MikTeX is LaTeX for Windows OS, meanwhile TeXLive is platform independent.  I use MikTeX, and if you have TeXLive, I don't know, how to work around it.

Comment: I did it! Your file works very well! thanks a lot! ;)